# Can one recover an algebraically closed field $k$ from its category of finitely generated $k$-algebras?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

More generally, given just the dots and arrows of a category (no taking sections!) and the information that for some unknown ring $R$ the category is the category of

- Classical varieties over $R$
- Affine schemes over $R$
- Schemes over $R$
- etc.

in what cases is there a unique ring $R$ (up to isomorphism) which produces my category (up to equivalence)?

Comment: All of the objects in these categories have maps to $\operatorname{spec}(R)$, so you recover $R$ by looking at the terminal object. Is that what you were looking for, or are you looking for something more specific?

Comment: @Andrew: you recover an object called $R$; there's an additional question of how to recover the underlying set and ring structure of $R$ itself.

Comment: @Andrew Sorry, no, that's not what I was looking for. You have only dots and arrows, and not the information of the sheaves, so as far as you know your terminal object is only a terminal object.

Comment: I'm cross posting this to math overflow: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/315717/can-one-recover-an-algebraically-closed-field-k-from-the-dots-and-arrows-of-it